# error: EOF for reading XML body of Post request

Tags: go

I'm getting `error: EOF` on console when I read the XML response body.

Below is my code.

```
resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/xml", payload)
if err != nil {
    response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
}

defer resp.Body.Close()
dec := xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body)

if debug == true {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("=========== Response ==================")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    fmt.Println("=========== Response Ends =============")
}

err = dec.Decode(respStruct)
```

I suspect `ioutil.ReadAll` is not working as expected.

Is there a reason why it's throwing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body)`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/xml/xml.go?s=5570:5607#L195) might already have read the content of resp.Body.
Hence the `EOF` message.

You can see the same error in "[`xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode` Giving `EOF` Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24880114/6309)"

Reading the `resp.Body` first, and using the string with [`xml.Unmarshal`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) would avoid the double read and the error message.

Note: a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095813/6309) shows that the best practice remains to use `xml.Decoder` instead of `xml.Unmarshal` when reading from streams.
So make sure you don't read `resp.Body` twice, and it will work.

Comment: How about `NewDecoder`? This seems to work fine but the thing is how would I read the response of this method into string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26095813/6309 shows that you are on the right track, but you need to be careful when reading resp.Body. My old answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24880114/6309) was about reading resp.Body in a string first, then using UnMarshal instead of NewDecoder.